# GameObject keeps bouncing after hitting a bouncy material

Tags: game-physics, unity-game-engine, bounce

I got a Edge collider as the ground and some square shaped sprites whit `RigidBody2D` and `BoxCollider2D` components. I've added a physics2D material to the ground with below properties to make the sprites bounce a little after hitting the ground.

```
Friction:   1
Bounciness: 0.2
```

When I run the game, sprites fall off and hit the ground with a little bouncing. But the never fully stop after hitting the ground and keep bouncing very slightly like their vibrating.

How can I make the sprites fully stop after 2 or 3 times hitting the ground by bouncing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with turning down the `Gravity` properties for the sprites. I've set it to 8 before and now changing it to 2 made the sprites stop vibrating after a few bouncings.